# Continous update of PDF in LyX

Tags: lyx

I was wondering if LyX has an option whereby the PDF output file updates as I am making changes to the master file.

Comment: This would be a wonderful feature to have and would save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is to my knowledge no such thing.

You can use Instant preview (http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/InstantPreview) for equations, and things you put inside a Preview box (Insert --> Preview), but I don't think there is an option for live updating the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

No such functionality in LyX yet. But under Linux one can consider using command line tools to achieve that.

Suppose the LyX project file is called *xx.lyx* and we use `pdflatex`. The principle is to use `entr` to monitor the change of *xx.lyx* and export *xx.lyx* to *xx.tex* on any change, and use `latexmk` to instantly compile and update the PDF file. Two steps are involved:

1. Open a terminal, `cd` into the LyX project folder and run

   `ls xx.lyx | entr lyx -e pdflatex -f xx.lyx`
2. Open another terminal, `cd` into the LyX project folder and run

   `latexmk -pvc -pdf xx.tex`

Comment: This seems really nice (I haven't tested it and don't use LyX so could skip the first step).  **But** a couple of things: (i) shouldn't the second terminal use `entr` to compile the file when it changes? (ii) You should probably note that this will update the pdf when you *save* the file, not just when you make changes (a good thing IMO).

Comment: I totally agree on (ii). Regarding (i): No, `entr` is not needed in the second terminal. Actually, `latexmk` detects any changes of *xx.tex* and its dependent files like figures. `entr`  is used in the first terminal to monitor the change of *xx.lyx*.

Comment: I didn't realise latexmk could monitor.  I might have used it if I'd known that!